# Raspberry PI4 + Coral TPU + Telit LTE get "Under-Voltage"

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi4, google-coral

I am using a Raspberry PI4 powered by the Raspberry power supply(5.1V,3A) and I have also a Coral TPU and a Telit Lte Modem attached on Raspberry USB 3.0 Ports Hub.
According with the Coral Power specifications, the USB TPU consumes about 500mhA.
Running `lsusb -v` seems Coral TPU to consumes 498mhA.
The Telit Lte Modem seems to consumes 500mhA and there is a VIA Labs, Inc. that consumes 100mhA

As explained in several articles and posts, Raspberry can support a maximum consumption of **1200mhA** on the USB ports(all).

Why I am getting a lot of **Under-Voltage Detected!** messages running `dmesg` if power consumed by the usb ports seems less than the maximum available?

Thank you in advace!

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up hardware or Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Too much bold, not enough on-topic.

Comment: This question goes here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com